# Why we use image Adjustement

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I was reading a [paper](http://ijcaonline.com/volume23/number1/pxc3873662.pdf) talk about OCR , and in it's procedure to capture a letter from image , there is `Image Adjustment` and I'm didn't understand what it's useful ? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is also in the paper. The author want each character to have the same sized box for OCR. As a `w` is lower than a `k`, in the **Image Adjustment** it is normalized to get the same box.